# Amazon Dodge Skills Practical? How do they work?

Tags: diablo-ii

I'm looking to make a Bowazon (probably Strafe centered, I'm not sure what other builds are viable)

The dodge skills sound great, but I'm curious as to how they work/how practical putting multiple points in them are. Not because I worry about the decreased bonuses as the skill gets higher (eventually points giving you like 2 extra chance, etc.) but because I'm not sure if really high Dodge is a GOOD thing. Like, how does it work? Does the time that dodging takes leave me open to further attacks that are unblock/undodgable until the dodge animation finishes, or does a second dodge simply happen without me seeing?

I don't want to get surrounded by enemies, dodge repeatedly and be unable to run away because of repetitive dodging or something along those lines.

Also, is the dodge percentage flat? Or is it modified in a manner similar to CTB? (Chance to Block)

Comment: I do remember that it takes frames to dodge attacks, and you can get into a dodge lock.  I don't remember if FHR makes you recover from dodge faster.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that might be the case. I should think they'd try to fix something like that because it's not very good if a skill can put you at a disadvantage, you know what I mean? Every other skill as far as I know is outright positive, with exceptions to outlined tradeoffs like "Sacrifice" and the "Impale" skills.

Answer (score 4):

Most builds recommend one point in dodge.

The good news it that you CAN dodge while attacking, so what frame your character is on doesn't matter when taking into account the dodge %.

You can always dodge, basically, there is no internal cooldown for dodging. So, just like attacking, you can dodge while dodging. Note: You'll notice a dodging animation that will cause your amazon to "reset" and go into the dodge framing again.

Amazons are rarely surrounded by enemies in D2. I've actually been killed because an enemy threw a spear at me, I dodged it, and it's brethren caught up to me while I was in the dodging animation.

It's modified by CTB, but you'll almost never see it unless you're running spears and a shield. Most Amazons are bowazons, unless you have a really godly spear or pike.